# In CodeIgniter, why can't I access $_GET variables in controller function from ajax get request

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, codeigniter-2

I tried this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?=base_url?>admin/zipcode/deleteselected/',
    data: {
        deletables: delList
    }
}).done(function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
})
```

in controller:

```
$deletables = $this -> input -> get('deletables');
$deletableids = json_decode($deletables, TRUE);
//Call to the model with deletable ids for multiple delete at a time
```

But I cant get the `get('deletables')` at all!
Any quicker help will help me a lot//Thanx

If I return from controller
    return $deletables;
I get blank response in console.log

Comment: Have you checked if it is in `$_POST`. Maybe you have default `$.ajax` settings set to use POST somewhere?

Comment: Well could be but my ajax calls are successful it's the case that i cant get the sent data from ajax in my controller.. Well you r saying about ajax setup right ? no i didnt do anything to it..

Comment: make sure you enable the get method in your codeigniter config file

Comment: try with $_GET and check

Comment: @bipen->It is there! But no luck!

Comment: why are you trying `json_decode` ? isn't `$this->input->get('deletables')` already an array ?

Comment: Yes it is! but in order to send it via ajax it deeded to be wrapped in as string and to parse it out as array I choose json_decode..though no issue with that came up because the line before that didnt get the sent value!

Comment: have you enabled query string in ci?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?=base_url?>admin/zipcode/deleteselected/',
    type: "GET",
data: {
    deletables: delList
}
}).done(function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
})
```

Comment: oh try changing <?=base_url?> to <?=base_url()?>